# Inverse square law motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

In gravity, a particle mass $m$ is in linear motion on the x axis with a mass $M$ at the origin. Initially $v_0$ velocity and position $x_0$. After time delta T, what is the new position and velocity, $v_1$ and $x_1$? I have a degree in physics from 50 years ago and have forgotten how to solve this!

Comment: Are you looking for the [Radial trajectory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_trajectory) article at Wikipedia?